# Open and edit file using cmd only in docker container

Tags: docker, cmd, containers, docker-for-windows

I'm building a docker image for windows. 
The dockerfile used for this image is split to build stange and runtime. For the runtime I'm using mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2 which is striped to the bone.
Inside the container I have a file, appsettings.json which I would like to open to view and also edit, but have no idea how.

Also is there anyway that I can use the CMD to install anything ? and if not what other choices do i have ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of modifying config inside of container you can map directory from host into container (`-v C:\config:C:\config`) - so you can edit config directly on host.

You can install applications in container, but each application usually require own set of options for that. Often it is easier to use chocolatey for that:

```
RUN powershell -NoProfile -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))"
RUN choco feature enable -n=allowGlobalConfirmation
RUN choco feature disable -n=showDownloadProgress
RUN choco install <your-app>
```

Comment: unfortunately the runtime image `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2` does not have powershell, so I cannot use powershell. This is one of my two problems because the actual web-app has a module with a direct dependency to powershell.  I could go ahead and use the sdk image instead since it containes powershell but it's 4x the size and don't want to do that.

Comment: then you can try to install software manually - check installer options and try to install it in your container. Yes, windows containers with reasonable functionality unfortunately huge, they are getting better but they far away from linux yet. If you need to install simple app which could be just copied after install you can install it in multi stage build and just copy into final image.

Comment: I've checked, mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2 has curl - so you have a way to download installer before running it.